# which version of windows 10 does windows 8 core upgrade to?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a PC running windows 8 core which is updated to windows 8.1.
I want to know what will happen when I upgrade to windows 10.
Which version of windows 10 will I get upgraded to when it is released?

Comment: Windows 10 Core (Home), I would guess.

Comment: ok in that case i am either buying pro or not upgrading lol..thanks

Comment: You can most probably pay for just an in-place upgrade from Core to Pro.

Answer (score 2):

8 Core is basically 10 Home.

sources:

- http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/06/windows-10-pricing-if-youre-not-upgrading-itll-cost-up-to-199/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions

Answer (score 0):

What edition of Windows will I get as part of this free upgrade?

*When you upgrade, you’ll stay on like-to-like editions of Windows. For example, Windows 7 Home Premium will upgrade to Windows 10 Home.*

[Microsoft Source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq)