# How do I check if my Windows 8/8.1 is home or professional?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

How do I check if my Windows 8/8.1 is home or professional ? In control panel > system it just says Windows 8.1 Single Language.

Comment: You have **WIndows 8.1 Single Language**.  What exactly is your question?  There is no such thing as Windows 8.1 Home and you don't have Windows 8.1 Professional.  Windows 8.1 is sometimes called **Windows 8.1 Core**.  **Windows 8.1 Single Lanuage** is Windows 8.1 Core with a single language pack.

Comment: I wanted to know which version do I have. Recently Microsoft announced "Windows Update Can’t Be Disabled (or Delayed) on Windows 10 Home". I won't upgrade if I have home edition.

Comment: If I have Win 8 home so I will get Win 10 home. Right ?

Comment: Stop calling it "Home". It's **not** "Home". It's either simply Win 8 or Win 8 core. Why are you concerned with it if this "microsoft announcment" is in regards to Win10?

Comment: Yes. Any computer with any version of Windows 7 **or** 8 will be able to upgrade to Win 10. If you have the core version, you'll have Win10 Core. If you have Win 8 Pro, you'll be updated to Win 10 Pro

Comment: Oh okay. Looks like I will be staying on Win 8.1.

Comment: As for what version you will get when you upgrade to Windows 10, there is  already a question with an answer, so I won't go repeating it. [Duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/922923/which-version-of-windows-10-does-windows-8-core-upgrade-to) of that which version of Windows 10 question.  [Actual](http://superuser.com/questions/923186/how-can-i-defer-updates-in-windows-10-home) duplicate of your actual question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have Pro. If it's Win 8 Core (what some would consider "Home" version) then the "Pro" simply won't be displayed.

You can also quickly check the Win version using <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then type: `winver`
Again, if you have Pro, you'll see it. If not, you wont.

[image]
Win 8 (**NOT** Pro)

[image]
 Win 8 Pro

Comment: you are best to vote to close this question since it has already been answered, instead of answering it again.

Comment: Not answering a question since it's "already been answered" is not my responsibility, since I'm not the one asking (**searching**) for answers. It's easier, and in my opinion better, to take 60 seconds to answer a question than to do what the OP should of done in the first place. Otherwise I spend at least 60 seconds searching to see if the question has been asked and if an answer exists. Then another 60 seconds marking and linking it a "duplicate," just for the OP to **not** have an answer. Trust me, the SE servers will be just fine.

Comment: So you have no responsibility in contributing or making this community better, interesting.

Comment: First, not at all what I said. Second, for reasons mentioned previously, we have different interpretations of what "contributing or making this community better" looks like. Third. You're **kinda** right actually. I don't have a responsibility. My wife and family? **thats** a responsibility. SU? lol. I come on here in my free time to offer my knowledge and experience, nothing more. Nothing less.

Comment: "different interpretations".......I have to remember that one, kind of like what your definition of is, is.